# How to have different behaviours for ON DELETE based on entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently working on an sql assignment that involves a database with doctors, patients and hospitals. Each hospital has a head doctor and we need to store the date when this doctor started as head of the hospital. I can either include this information in the doctor table, hospital table, or its own table. I am required to have the following functionality:

"When you delete a doctor, cause an error to occur if the doctor is head of the hospital and do a cascade delete when you delete a doctor who is treating patients."

How am I supposed to have different behaviour for on delete depending on which doctor is being deleted???

My first thought was this but it doesnt seem to work:

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR (
 LiscenceNumber CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
 Firstname VARCHAR(20), 
 Lastname VARCHAR(20), 
 Specialty VARCHAR(30), 
 LiscenceDate DATE, 
 IsHead BOOLEAN, 
 HeadDate DATE, 
 HospitalCode CHAR(3), 
 FOREIGN KEY (HospitalCode) REFERENCES Hospital(Code) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE WHERE IsHead = False
)
```

Any ideas? I would really appreciate any help you have.

Comment: You'd probably need to write a `DELETE` trigger

Comment: *do a cascade delete when you delete a doctor who is treating patients.*: this means that when a doctor is deleted, you want to delete their patients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you delete a doctor, cause an error to occur if the doctor is head of the hospital and do a cascade delete when you delete a doctor who is treating patients.

I would go for the following design:

- create a `doctors` table (possibly with a foreign key referencing the hospital they work at, but that's not the most important thing)
- create a `hospitals` table with a `head_doctor_id` that references the primary key of the `doctors` table; this constraint prevents a "main" doctor to be deleted
- create a `patients` table that references a hospital and a doctor; the foreign key to the `doctors` table should have an `on delete` clause that deletes a patient when its doctor is deleted

Sample schema:

```
create table doctors(
    id int primary key,
    ...
);

create table hospitals(
    id int primary key,
    ...
    head_doctor_id int,
    foreign key(head_doctor_id) references doctors(id)
);

create table patients(
    id int primary key,
    ...
    hospital_id int,
    doctor_id int,
    foreign key(hospital_id) references hospitals(id)
    foreign key(doctor_id) references doctors(id) on delete cascade
)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your fast response!!

Comment: What if i had to implement a Treats table because a patient can have more than one doctor? How would I still implement the above logic?

Comment: @jewelltaylor9430: well, instead of storing the `doctor_id` in the `patients` table, you would create a bridge table, like `patients_doctors(id, doctor_id, patient_id)`, each referencing their respective tables with a foreign key and `on delete cascade`. When a doctor (or a patient) is deleted, the corresponding record in the  bridge table would get deleted too.